# What font is used in this "Four Seasons Plumbing" logo?

Tags: font-identification

I was wondering if anyone might know what this font is.

[image]

I've searched Google fonts, Typekit and tried Whatthefont, but can not seem to find it.

If someone might know what font this is I would greatly appreciate it.

Points to look at:

- The n is pretty unique as the second leg drops down lower than the
  first.
- The g is also pretty unique.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't know what font it is, but I suddenly feel like listening to the BeeGees and putting on a velvet suit with huge lapels. :)

Comment: @Scott It's funny you say that because that's exactly what I'm listening to and wearing. How strange is that. :P

Comment: I wish all font questions showed effort like this one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This font is probably [Tabasco Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/softmaker/tabasco/) with some stroke effects applied:

[image]

Comment: thanks so much! How did you figure it out? Or how did you get what the font to recognize it? Just curious for future projects.

Comment: Sometimes designers are just familiar from past projects, sometimes they use identification services like What the font http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ or even what the font's forum http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum

Comment: @echo I found another pic of the label and fed it up to whatthefont :)